# visual studio code anaconda problems

Tags: python, anaconda

I am attempting to run a python code on visual studio code but to do so I needed ta-lib. I was recommended to install ta-lib using anaconda, so I got anaconda and it asked me to set it as my primary python so I did. After doing so, I tried to run my code but it gave:

```
conda activate base
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ conda activate base
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: 
(conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundExceptio
    n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I then attempted to uninstall anaconda but after doing so it was still set as my primary python.

Does anyone know of a way to get visual studio code to not reference anaconda as the primary python or get visual studio code to work with anaconda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a .py file opened, in the bottom left corner you should be able to see something like `Python 3.9.4 64 bit`, or something python related. then click on it and it will look something like this[image]

Then from there you can select the python interpreter that you want to use.